# Django admin dropdown of 1000s of users

Tags: django, django-admin

Hypothetically: I have a model called Car, which relates to one user. My concern is within the default Django Admin. I assign a user to a car via a drop down (this is default Django behavior, so I'm told).

**What happens when I have 1000s+ of users to pick from in the drop down. Does the admin deal with this, if so how?**

Comment: 2019: Awesome auto complete field: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54341270/5506400

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The default admin UI displays a dropdown list. Use the `raw_id_fields` option to get a pop-up window, via a search button. This window lets you find and select the linked object. See the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields

> By default, Django’s admin uses a select-box interface () for
>   fields that are ForeignKey. Sometimes you don’t want to incur the
>   overhead of having to select all the related instances to display in
>   the drop-down.

Comment: So does this provide a lookup? Admin users won't know the id?

Comment: Yes there is a search icon next to the input which can be used to find the id.

Answer (score 5):

You can look into `django-grappelli`, which is an app that enhances the admin interface. The [documentation](https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html#autocomplete-lookups) describes an autocomplete for `ForeignKey` or `ManyToMany` relationships, using `raw_id_fields`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use django-select2 plugin https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2.

You can do something like:

```
from django_select2 import AutoModelSelect2Field

class CategoryChoices(AutoModelSelect2Field):
    queryset = models.Category.objects
    search_fields = ['name__icontains', 'code__icontains']

class NewsAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = CategoryChoices()

    class Meta:
        model = models.News
        exclude = ()

# register in admin
class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = NewsAdminForm
admin.site.register(News, NewsAdmin)
```

Comment: From the new `django-select2` repo: "Django's admin comes with builtin support for Select2 via the [autocomplete_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) feature."