# raw_id_fields: How to show a name instead of id?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Customizing a Django Admin panel, I'm using [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) to select a ForeignKey from a Model which has thousands of elements, because the default select-box drop-down is inconvenient with so many elements.

It works but it shows the id as can be seen on this image:
[image]

Is there any way to show the name or other field instead of the id? Or, is there any better way to accomplish this than using `raw_id_fields`?

This is my code in `models.py`:

```
class Structure(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, verbose_name = _('name'))
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', verbose_name = _('parent'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.name)
```

In `admin.py`:

```
class StructureAdmin(tree_editor.TreeEditor):
    search_fields = ('name',)
    raw_id_fields = ('parent',)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809122/how-to-show-raw-id-value-of-a-manytomany-relation-in-the-django-admin

Comment: if you just want get rid of huge data loading and editing is not needed, use `readonly_fields = ('parent', )`.

Answer (score 44):

From Django 2.0 you can use `autocomplete_fields`. It will work just like ajax select2.

In `admin.py`

```
class StructureAdmin(tree_editor.TreeEditor):
    search_fields = ('name',)
    autocomplete_fields = ('parent',)
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields

Comment: Wow, I have been developing in Django professionally for five years, and somehow never came across `autocomplete_fields`. Fantastic feature.

Comment: Yes this must be the correct answer. Very cool feature and built-in as well.

Answer (score 8):

I've also researched this and I don't think it's possible. I think the best you can do is display the unicode of the field next to the raw id field: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2108/

Alternatively, you can display the unicode and a link to the value's corresponding admin change page: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2217/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried the last snippet, but it only shows the unicode and the link when I save the Structure and I open it again. Do you know how can I show the same but when I choose the raw_id?

Comment: @A.Vila I'm having the same behavior, did you have any other alternatives ?

Answer (score 5):

It seems this plugin: https://github.com/lincolnloop/django-dynamic-raw-id

does what you want:

(copied from the doc):

Usage

To start using django-dynamic-raw-id in your application all you need to do is implement DynamicRawIDMixin in your ModelAdmin class and add the desired fields to a list of dynamic_raw_id_fields:

```
from dynamic_raw_id.admin import DynamicRawIDMixin

class UserProfileAdmin(DynamicRawIDMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    dynamic_raw_id_fields = ('user',)
```

You can use dynamic_raw_id widgets in a Admin filter as well:

```
from dynamic_raw_id.admin import DynamicRawIDMixin
from dynamic_raw_id.filters import DynamicRawIDFilter

class UserProfileAdmin(DynamicRawIDMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (
        ('dynamic_raw_id_fk', DynamicRawIDFilter),
    )
```

Comment: @coup Regarding your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24030698) for *"Change salmonella to dynamic_raw_id"*, it's well worth adding *why*, suggested edit reviewers are not necessarily going to investigate why you are making such a change, maybe next time mention something along the lines of *"salmonella renamed to dynamic_raw_id"* as per documentation. As you can see from the link, your edit did get 1 rejection vote for conflicting with what the user wrote, likely because the editor couldn't understand *why* you made the change.

Answer (score 2):

For the representation of an object use `__unicode__`

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

In Python 3 use

```
def __str__(self):
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already used __unicode__. I've updated the question with the code I've used in my model. Maybe I've missed something...

Comment: is 'Structure' your FK table? you need unicode on the FK model.

Comment: Yes, it's a TreeForeignKey to itself: `parent = TreeForeignKey('self', [...] )`

Comment: I had the same issue but `__unicode__` does not solve it, the id is still shown. Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: __unicode__ does not solve mine too. using python3 and django1.7 here.

Comment: @castiel Strings are handled differently in Python 3 vs 2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods

Comment: @DiegoHerranz in Python 3 use `` __str__(self)``