# Django admin limit model from foreign key

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I have the following model setup:

The problem is that when I try to pull the object up in the admin page, computer_names links to several hundred thousand rows that aren't relevant and the page never loads. How can I filter computer_names to only the user selected objects for the ManyToMany field?

```
class ScoringException(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_modified']
    requester = models.CharField('Requester',max_length=50,null=False,blank=False)
    computer_names = models.ManyToManyField(Computer)
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain)
    exception_kpi_types = models.ManyToManyField(ScoringType)
    expiration_date = models.DateField('Expiration Date')
    reason = models.CharField('Reason',max_length=1000,null=False,blank=False)
    approved = models.BooleanField('Approved')
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField('Date Updated',auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Can you try another widget `filter_horizontal` and see if the widget would make it a little better? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `raw_id_fields` in the admin so that Django doesn't render the hundred thousand rows of data:

```
@admin.register(ScoringException)
class ScoringExceptionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    raw_id_fields = ['computer_names']
```

With `raw_id_fields`, Django will display the list of ids for selected m2m objects. A search button is also added to make adding new objects for the m2m relationship easier.

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) for more information.

Comment: That is very cool. Is there anyway to show the actual text rather than the IDs? It would be hard for a user to visualize what is going on by looking at an ID list

Comment: Unfortunately not built-in for Django, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190228/raw-id-fields-how-to-show-a-name-instead-of-id). The answer also contain links to code snippets for rendering additional information for raw_id_fields.