# How to insert a search engine instead of a list in the Django model

Tags: python, django, search

I am creating a model and a field is presented as a list, I would like it not to be a list but a search engine, this in the administrator when I want to insert new data in my table, I would like the author part to be a search engine and not a list.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

[image: [enter image description here]()]

I don't know if this can be done in the model.

Answer (score 0):

In the `ModelAdmin`, you can make the item searchable, with:

```
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['author']
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: You can set a field [**`editable=False`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#editable). Then the field does not show up in the `ModelForm`s and `ModelAdmin`s by default. In this case for example with `publish`.

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is **raw_id_fields** in your admin. This allows you to input the id directly or look up the related table by clicking the search icon.

In your model admin:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
```

Comment: This will show the `id` of the user instead of its username...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem : Yes, but if you override the __str__ in the user model to return the username(or whatever) it will show it beside the id.

Comment: no, the `raw_id`, well... shows the raw id https://stackoverflow.com/q/15190228/67579

Comment: That's a ManyToMany not ForeignKey.  When adding you could look up that table and select the username, once added the username will appear whenever you check or try to change the post. I can't post a photo here!